# Adding Lat/Long Coordinates to Frame in Print Layout

Tags: qgis, coordinates, print-composer, grids-graticules, antarctica

I am still learning how to use QGIS: I am making a map of a location in Antarctica, so I am using WGS 84/Antarctic Polar Stereographic coordinates (EPSG:3031).  I have put the map into a print layout and added a frame to it, but I need to add coordinates to the frame in decimal degrees (i.e. "72.98°S").  When I examine the "Draw Coordinates" section of the "Item Properties" tab, the "Format" dropdown menu offers "Decimal", "Decimal with Suffix", and "Custom" options.

Is "Custom" what I need to use for this?

If so, can you please explain for me how to use it to convert my coordinates into a lat/long format, or point me towards a guide/documentation on how to do so?

---

[image]

In response to the answer which suggested I change the "Format" of the frame to "Degree, Minute with Suffix", please see here a screenshot of my "Item Properties" panel.

Do you know why I only get the three options shown here?

Answer (score 0):

You need add a grid (hitting the plus sign) under 'Grids' in Item Properties. Then go to Modify Grid to go to the Map Grid Properties window. Make sure to set your CRS too EPSG:3031 CRS box, and then "Degree, Minute with Suffix" should be available to use.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your response!  Unfortunately, even after changing the CRS to "EPSG:3031 - WGS 84 / Antarctic Polar Stereographic", when I attempt to change the format to "Degree, Minute with Suffix", I only get the three options listed above (and my coordinates remain, e.g., "1803573.000E").  Do you know what might be preventing me from accessing "Degree, Minute with Suffix"?

EDIT: sorry for my inexperience, but I am not sure how to attach an image to a comment.  I have attached a screenshot of what my "Item Properties" panel looks like in an "answer", however.

Answer (score 0):

That might be because the units for EPSG: 3031 is in meters. You need to use a CRS that uses geographic units (Lat and Long), like EPSG: 4326. There are many options if you type "Geographic Coordinate Systems" in the Filter in the CRS window. Depending on what CRS your map data is in, you may need to transform (Raster -> Projections -> Warp (reproject)) your data so that it's using your chosen geographic CRS.

[image]

Comment: This looks like it should be an edit to your answer, rather than a new answer.  Please take the [Tour] to make sure that you are using this site for focused Q&A rather than as a discussion forum (for which it is not designed.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

As @PolyGeo have said your CRS is not defined in degree as unit but metre, so the grid for your CRS will be based on your coordinate unit multiplicated by an interval so always be metre.

For my understanding : you want coordinate label shown in degree and a gird following latitude axis and longitude axis (the grid will not be straight, as it is not in the same projection system).

To do this you have to create a map in your layout with the projection system  EPSG:3031 then add a grid. Set this grid to follow CRS EPSG:4326, and then you have the option to follow Decimal with suffix and the coordinate precision to two.

Here is the result and the settings used.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: As you are new, if you want, you can use the top arrow to any answer that was useful and to choose one as an answer to your problem with the V tick.